# How to isolate single observations (NOT outliers) from a group in boxplot ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to visualise group differences in mean (6 groups) using ggplot2 boxplot. Please see the code below. However, as I am also interested in visualising the value for three individuals that belong to one of these groups (not as a group of three but rather think about it as three single cases) to the means of all groups even the group they are taken from. I was wondering how could I isolate these three observations so that they would be marked with different symbols (star; triangle etc) on the actual boxplot for the group they are part of. It could not be done as setting them as outliers as they are not far away from the mean in comparison to the other subjects in the group. This obviously could be done in pain but that`s just not elegant now :).

I am open to any suggestion and will be very grateful for your input! 
Cheers!

```
mean.n <- function(x){
return(c(y = median(x)*0.97, label = round(mean(x),2)))
}
FA<-ggplot(data, aes(factor(group), averFA, label=rownames(data))) + 
 ylim(0.35, 0.5) +
geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "#3366FF") +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean.n, geom = "text", fun.y = mean, colour = "red")
```

Comment: Why don't you pass a data.frame with your 3 cases to `geom_point`?

Comment: This would be pretty straightforward, but without access to `data` and knowing which points you're isolating, it's just guesswork. You can do `dput(data)` to give acces to `data`.